# How can I make a specific image stop loading in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, images, download, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

I don't want to prevent all images from loading or stop loading everything, I just want to stop loading an individual image after I've seen that it's probably not something I care about so I can use that bandwidth for something else.

My internet is very slow, but I still like browsing sites like tumblr, imgur, etc. that have lots of images. It seems like GIFs are getting more and more common and they can be several megabytes each... my internet just can't handle it.

When I right-click a broken/unloaded image in Firefox, there's an option to reload the image. I essentially want the counterpart to that: to right-click a still-loading image and stop the download. Is this possible? Greasemonkey script, extension, I'll take any method.

Answer (score 1):

[The Adblock Plus add-on](https://adblockplus.org/) is perfect for this and helps with bandwidth by blocking a whole lot of crud as well.

With the extension installed:

1. Right-click on the offending image and
2. Select `Adblock Plus: Block image...`.
   [(Click for a larger image)

   [image: Screenshot of selecting image to block]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKYW.gif)
3. Select your desired rule, usually choosing the prefilled `Custom` rule works best for single images.
4. Click <kbd>Add filter</kbd>.
5. Voilà, that image is now automatically blocked from now on!
   [(Click for a larger image)

   [image: Final filter-add steps]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nogmb.gif)

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't ideal... unless there's an easier way to unblock images I don't know about. I might want to come back later and check out the images I blocked. I don't want them gone forever. Also, does this actually stop the download immediately?

Comment: You didn't say anything about unblocking in your question!  Nevertheless, you can easily see a list of everything that AdBlock blocks, using the appropriate menu item that AdBlock provides (Or *Ctrl* + *Shift* + *V* on most installations).  ... Adblock prevents the item from ever loading in the first place.